# siri shortcut button (INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton) shows wrong title when have multiple shortcuts (NSUserActivity)

Tags: ios, swift, ios12, sirishortcuts

I've 2 siri shortcuts in my App. 
I use NSUserActivity to donate these shortcuts. I've also created 2 NSUserActivityTypes in my info.plist.

There are 2 view controllers which handle these shortcuts (1 view controller for 1 shortcut).

If I add 1 siri shortcut from 1 view controller and then go to 2nd view controller the native siri shortcut button (`INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton`) on 2nd view controller automatically picks the first shortcut (created from 1st view controller) and shows "Added to Siri" with suggested phrase instead of showing "Add to Siri" button. I double checked that each `NSUserActivity` has different identifier but still somehow its picks the wrong shortcut.

View Controller 1:

```
let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.activity.type1")
userActivity.isEligibleForSearch = true
userActivity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
userActivity.title = shortcut.title
userActivity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = suggestedPhrase

let attributes = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeItem as String)
attributes.contentDescription = description
userActivity.contentAttributeSet = attributes
let shortcut = INShortcut(userActivity: userActivity)
let siriButton = INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton(style: .whiteOutline)
siriButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
siriButton.shortcut = shortcut
self.view.addSubview(siriButton)
```

View Controller 2:

```
let userActivity2 = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.activity.type2")
userActivity2.isEligibleForSearch = true
userActivity2.isEligibleForPrediction = true
userActivity2.title = shortcut.title
userActivity2.suggestedInvocationPhrase = suggestedPhrase

let attributes = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeItem as String)
attributes.contentDescription = description
userActivity2.contentAttributeSet = attributes

let shortcut = INShortcut(userActivity: userActivity2)
let siriButton = INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton(style: .whiteOutline)
siriButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
siriButton.shortcut = shortcut
self.view.addSubview(siriButton)
```

A similar thing happens when I delete the App and reinstall without deleting the shortcuts from Phone's Settings App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like its an IOS bug. I figured out a workaround for this problem. You have to create a new siri button every time the user add/edit the siri shortcut. Before creating siri button do the following things

1- Get all the voice shortcuts from `INVoiceShortcutCenter` by calling the function. Note that this happens asynchronously, so you need to do it some time before you need the data (e.g. in your AppDelegate). You'll also need to re-load this whenever the user adds a Siri Shortcut (probably in the `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate.addVoiceShortcutViewController(_:didFinishWith:error)` method).

```
INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.getAllVoiceShortcuts  { (voiceShortcutsFromCenter, error) in
    guard let voiceShortcutsFromCenter = voiceShortcutsFromCenter else {
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                os_log("Failed to fetch voice shortcuts with error: %@", log: OSLog.default, type: .error, error)
            }
            return
        }
        self.voiceShortcuts = voiceShortcutsFromCenter
}
```

2- In View Controller-1 check if the shortcut is already added or not by iterating all the voice shortcuts

```
let voiceShorcut = voiceShortcuts.first { (voiceShortcut) -> Bool in
    if let activity = voiceShortcut.shortcut.userActivity, activity.activityType == "com.activity.type1" {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

3- If your voice shortcut is registered then pass the `INShortcut` to siri button otherwise don't set it.

```
if voiceShorcut != nil {
    let shortcut = INShortcut(userActivity: userActivity1)
    siriButton.shortcut = shortcut
}
```

Do the same thing in Second View Controller.

Answer (score 2):

It's iOS 12.0 bug.
You can fix it by update INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton.voiceShortcut with correct value.
Use KVO to observe "voiceShortcut" property and when it change assign correct value to it.

Comment: I don't see a `voiceShortcut` property on `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton` - is this private?

Comment: Okay, without even observing, I was able to fix it by just calling `[addToSiriButton setValue:voiceShortcut forKey:@"voiceShortcut"]` where I was once calling `addToSiriButton.shortcut = voiceShortcut.shortcut;`.

Comment: @Vitaliy Alekseev can you explain better this?

Answer (score 0):

I've moved to intents setup now and I find that even having just one intent setup and working the **INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton** is not able to track my shortcut. Once phrase is recorded it shows the Added to Siri with phrase.

But every time the app relaunches the Add to Siri button shows up instead of the Added to Siri button with recorded phrase.

I have tried going by Bilal's suggestion and although I can see the INVoiceShortcutCenter showing me my shortcut as present it doesn't loaded it into the Siri button.

My code looks like this for the button itself.

```
 private func addSiriButton() {
    let addShortcutButton = INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton(style: .blackOutline)
    addShortcutButton.delegate = self

    addShortcutButton.shortcut = INShortcut(intent: engine.intent )
    addShortcutButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    siriButtonSubView.addSubview(addShortcutButton)
    siriButtonSubView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addShortcutButton.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    siriButtonSubView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addShortcutButton.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

I have all the protocols implement and I had a close look at the Soup app but just can't figure out what drives this inaccuracy.

Funny enough,  even British Airways app developers have given up on that as their button has exactly the same fault behaviour.

**Update**: I've built another test project with minimal amount implementation for the Intent and the Add to Siri and Added to Siri works perfectly. I'm guessing at this point that there is something in my own apps codebase that is causing this unwanted behaviour.

**update 2** Just wanted to let everyone know I have fixed the issue. Using intents works fine but there is definitely a little sensitivity in the Intents definition file itself. All I had to do is create a new intent which then was generated and that worked. Seems my initial intent was somehow corrupt but there were no errors. After creating another intent and re-assigning intent handling function to that it all worked as intended. (pun intended)

Comment: Is there a way, you display "Added to Siri" without phrase below it? I see some of the app doing it but could not figure it myself.

Comment: Hi Rumin, I haven't seen a way to remove the text below.The text itself is only added once the phrase has been recorded to server as a reminder that you have a phrase, this is one reason Apple suggests a short memorable phrase. Another reason the text is displayed is because the whole Add To Siri Button is localisable so you can localise the "Add to Siri" and also the recorded phrase.

Comment: Just had another look at the INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton and it is just a subclass of the UIButton which might mean that you can set label to whatever you want, although I'm still not 100% on that. In fact the INUIAddVoiceShortcutButtonStyle is part Init that sets the button style and it is only a  { get } property.

Comment: yeah thank you Dan! Looks like "Added to Siri" text is default implementation from Apple after you set the phrase. If I try to set the title, it overlaps that text.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I had an existing intent and working configuration, but added a new parameter. However, in my Intent configuration, I had not added the new parameter `name` to a supported combination under the **Shortcuts app** section.

For example, if I had two properties `myId` and `myName`, and specified them as such:

```
let intent = MyIntent()
intent.myId = 1234
intent.myName = "banana"
```

Then I would need a supported combination of `myId, myName` in my intents definition file. In my particular case, I had forgotten `myName` so the `INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton` was attempting to do a lookup using `myId, myName` but didn't know how.

Answer (score -1):

I just fixed this issue myself by changing my implementation (originally based on the soupchef app) to this code sample provided by apple (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inuiaddvoiceshortcutbutton):

**EDIT: I added code that shows how I create and pass in the shortcutObject (INShortcut) for both UserActivity and custom Intent shortcuts.**

The Shortcut class is an enum that contains a computed property called intent that returns an instantiation of the custom intent.

```
private func addShortcutButton(shortcut: Shortcut, parentViewController: UIViewController, shortcutViewControllerDelegate: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate) {
    guard let view = parentViewController.view else { return }

    if let intent = shortcut.intent {
        shortcutObject = INShortcut(intent: intent)
    } else if let userActivity = view.userActivity {
        shortcutObject = INShortcut(userActivity: userActivity)
    }

    self.shortcutViewControllerDelegate = shortcutViewControllerDelegate
    addSiriButton(to: shortcutButtonContainer)
}

func addSiriButton(to view: UIView) {
    let button = INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton(style: .whiteOutline)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(button)
    view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addToSiri(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

// Present the Add Shortcut view controller after the
// user taps the "Add to Siri" button.
@objc
func addToSiri(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let shortcutObject = shortcutObject else { return }
    let viewController = INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController(shortcut: shortcutObject)
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    viewController.delegate = shortcutViewControllerDelegate
    parentViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: The problem is with multiple shortcuts. Where are you handling multiple shortcuts?

Comment: I have a property where I set the user activity for the shortcut I&#39;d like to use and use it to create the INShortcut.
 I&#39;ll update this later with more detailed code when I get back to my dev machine.

Comment: Hey. I've fighting with this setup at the moment. Could you elaborate how you used the Apple provided example for UserActivity please? if let shortcut = INShortcut( userAcivity: Do you use a function to selection activity to go in here?

Comment: Dan, I pass in the view controller that has the donated user activity (parentViewController) and I pull the userActivity from its view.  I added more code to show that.

Answer (score -1):

So we can't use the default Siri button, you have to use custom UIButton.
The class VoiceShortcutsManager will check all the voice intents and then we can search that list check if exist one match if yes so we should suggest edition if not we should suggest adding.

```
public class VoiceShortcutsManager {

    private var voiceShortcuts: [INVoiceShortcut] = []

    public init() {

        updateVoiceShortcuts(completion: nil)
    }


    public func voiceShortcut(for order: DeviceIntent, powerState: State) -> INVoiceShortcut? {

        for element in voiceShortcuts {

            guard let intent = element.shortcut.intent as? ToggleStateIntent else {
                continue
            }
            let deviceIntent = DeviceIntent(identifier: intent.device?.identifier, display: intent.device?.displayString ?? "")
            if(order == deviceIntent && powerState == intent.state) {
                return element
            }
        }
        return nil
    }


    public func updateVoiceShortcuts(completion: (() -> Void)?) {

        INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.getAllVoiceShortcuts { (voiceShortcutsFromCenter, error) in
            guard let voiceShortcutsFromCenter = voiceShortcutsFromCenter else {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed to fetch voice shortcuts with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                return
            }
            self.voiceShortcuts = voiceShortcutsFromCenter
            if let completion = completion {
                completion()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And then implement in your ViewController

```
class SiriAddViewController: ViewController {

    let voiceShortcutManager = VoiceShortcutsManager.init()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        contentView.btnTest.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.testBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    ...


    @objc func testBtn() {

        let deviceIntent = DeviceIntent(identifier: smartPlug.deviceID, display: smartPlug.alias)

        //is action already has a shortcut, update shortcut else create shortcut
        if let shortcut = voiceShortcutManager.voiceShortcut(for: deviceIntent, powerState: .off) {

            let editVoiceShortcutViewController = INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController(voiceShortcut: shortcut)
            editVoiceShortcutViewController.delegate = self
            present(editVoiceShortcutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if let shortcut = INShortcut(intent: intentTurnOff) {

            let addVoiceShortcutVC = INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController(shortcut: shortcut)
            addVoiceShortcutVC.delegate = self
            present(addVoiceShortcutVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}


@available(iOS 12.0, *)
extension SiriAddViewController: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButtonDelegate {


    func present(_ addVoiceShortcutViewController: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController, for addVoiceShortcutButton: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton) {
        addVoiceShortcutViewController.delegate = self
        addVoiceShortcutViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        present(addVoiceShortcutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func present(_ editVoiceShortcutViewController: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController, for addVoiceShortcutButton: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton) {

        editVoiceShortcutViewController.delegate = self
        editVoiceShortcutViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        present(editVoiceShortcutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}


@available(iOS 12.0, *)
extension SiriAddViewController: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate {

    func addVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController, didFinishWith voiceShortcut: INVoiceShortcut?, error: Error?) {

        voiceShortcutManager.updateVoiceShortcuts(completion: nil)
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func addVoiceShortcutViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}


@available(iOS 12.0, *)
extension SiriAddViewController: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate {


    func editVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController, didUpdate voiceShortcut: INVoiceShortcut?, error: Error?) {

        voiceShortcutManager.updateVoiceShortcuts(completion: nil)
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func editVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController, didDeleteVoiceShortcutWithIdentifier deletedVoiceShortcutIdentifier: UUID) {

        voiceShortcutManager.updateVoiceShortcuts(completion: nil)
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func editVoiceShortcutViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController) {

        voiceShortcutManager.updateVoiceShortcuts(completion: nil)
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
}
```

This code was inspired/copy from this webpage:
https://www.nodesagency.com/test-drive-a-siri-shortcuts-intro/

Answer (score -1):

My experience with solving this was a little different. Some intents added via the Add to Siri button worked, which adjusted to "Added to Siri", while others didn't. I realised the actions that worked didn't require parameters.

After setting default values for intents that exposed parameters, which are passed into **INShortcut** (and then assigned to **INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton**), all buttons updated their state correctly!